# Controller function calls more than once in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, angularjs-controller

I am making mobile application with using `JQuery Mobile` and `AngularJs`
I am currently using single page structure here is my sample

```
<body  ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-role="page" id="foodscreen" ng-controller="foodModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="addfood" ng-controller="foodModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="foodLogDetail" ng-controller="foodModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <!--  Exercise Module  -->
    <div data-role="page" id="exercisescreen" ng-controller="exerciseModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="addexercise" ng-controller="exerciseModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="exerciseLogDetail" ng-controller="exerciseModule">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My first 3 pages required `Controller` named `foodModule` while other 3 required is `exerciseModule` but by doing this i am getting problem that my controller function called 3 times if i write only on 1 page the other pages not working
is there any solution that i could use to avoid this problem?

**Update**

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/HmNY5/10/) of my app

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each controller group inside a dedicated [div] element and attach each controller only once:

```
<body  ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="foodModule">
    <div data-role="page" id="foodscreen">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="addfood">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="foodLogDetail">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  Exercise Module  -->
  <div ng-controller="exerciseModule">
    <div data-role="page" id="exercisescreen">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="addexercise">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="exerciseLogDetail">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer_include"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: it will effect other things like, i will do some work on page that id is `addfood` after some processing it will redirect to page that id is `foodscreen` but when processing finish the page is not display just URL in address-bar changes but not display page content

Comment: Show rest of the code. It's is not clear how your redirection actually works. Setup a plunker.

Comment: That's nice but your fiddle should actually harbour only the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the exact problem. Sorry, but I don't intend to go through your whole application.

Comment: ahh :) its ok 
but its the minimum amount :)